# Grabbing just the subfolder and filename from current page

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I couldn't find another questions with the exact specs I'm needing here. So I'm posting this.

I need to use php to grab the url of the current page.
http//example.com/mysubfolder/filename.php

I need it to print out:
mysubfolder/filename

And if the filename.php has a get formula ?action=move or ?id=798 I would simply need to strip those portions off. The farthest I've seen in manuals will help to subtract only a specific portion of the .?action=*doesntchangeathing*

Most of what I have seen includes just the filename or a complete list of subfolders, not just one and would be using an absolute path rather than the url.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and cut filename extension and leading slash, so resulted expression may look something like this:

```
$path = implode('/', [trim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/'), pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)]);
```

Comment: worked perfectly. Will mod it with str_replace to change  _ to space with some upper casing XD